# PHP how to limit lines in a string?

Tags: php

i have a variable like the following and i want a function to only keep the first 20 lines, so it will strips any additional \n lines more than 20.

```
<?php
$mytext="Line1
Line2
Line3
....."

keeptwentyline($mytext);
?>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose a *(maybe a bit dumb ^^ )* solution would be to :

- [`explode`](https://www.php.net/explode) the string into an array of lines
- keep only the X first lines, using, for instance, [`array_slice`](http://fr.php.net/array_slice)
- [`implode`](https://www.php.net/implode) those back into a string.

Something like that would correspond to this idea :

```
var_dump(keepXlines($mytext, 5));

function keepXLines($str, $num=10) {
    $lines = explode("\n", $str);
    $firsts = array_slice($lines, 0, $num);
    return implode("\n", $firsts);
}
```

Note : I passed the number of lines as a parameter -- that way, the function can be used elsewhere ;-)

And if the parameter is not given, it takes the default value : 10

But there might be some clever way ^^

*(that one will probably need qiute some memory, to copy the string into an array, extract the first lines, re-create a string...)*

Comment: that's the best I could come up with :)

Comment: I see I'm not the only one who got that idea ^^ *(Even though I would be curious about other ways, actually ^^ )*

Comment: Indeed :-) what I meant was more like *"without explode/implode"* -- ho, I see you've edited your answer, since ;-)

Answer (score 8):

```
function keeptwentyline($string)
{
     $string = explode("\n", $string);
     array_splice($string, 20);
     return implode("\n", $string);
}
```

Or (probably faster)

```
function keepLines($string, $lines = 20)
{
    for ($offset = 0, $x = 0; $x < $lines; $x++) {
        $offset = strpos($string, "\n", $offset) + 1;
    }

    return substr($string, 0, $offset);
}
```