# PHP limited lines or characters in output

Tags: php, html, css, substr

I got a weird Problem here, need your help. PHP Language.

Suppose I have a Output like this:

> A
>   B
>   C
>   D
>   E

Now Instead of 5 Lines, I want out in 2 Lines and 3rd line will be "more" which will take him to another page for details(I know how to place anchor tag :S)

And if The ouput is like

> This is a big paragraph of 5 lines or maybe more, but what I want to display is only first 100(or some first n Characters). Repeated This is a big paragraph of 5 lines or maybe more, but what I want to display is only first 100(or some first n Characters)This is a big paragraph of 5 lines or maybe more, but what I want to display is only first 100(or some first n Characters)This is a big paragraph of 5 lines or maybe more, but what I want to display is only first 100(or some first n Characters)This is a big paragraph of 5 lines or maybe more, but what I want to display is only first 100(or some first n Characters).

Instead of this I want to display only first 100 characters and then a more button which will take to a detailed page.

The Second Problem can be solved with php function substr, but what about the first one ?  I need both cases to work at same place, like if input has some list(hell of newline characters) at starting then only top 2 lines will be printed And if it is a paragraph then only first 100(or some n) characters(or even words) will be printed.
Any Guesses ?

Comment: How is this MySQL related?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449602/php-how-to-limit-lines-in-a-string

Comment: I am getting my data from database. So its not stored in a file.

Comment: Derek S, The next line concept is cool, but what about limited characters ?

Comment: What kind of line break are you using? Because if you are trying to limit the number of lines we need to know what lines means in that case <br>, <p>, "\n"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr` and then ajax to load the whole string. But you can also use CSS to display first X lines - set `height` and `overflow: hidden`. Then again javascript to unset the height and overflow.

Comment: Thanks, Easy And Simple.

Answer (score 0):

My implementation would be something like this:

```
if (strpos("\n", $mytext) > -1) {
    $textarray = explode("\n", $mytext);
    $output = $textarray[0] . "\n" . $textarray[1];
} else {
    $output = $mytext;
}
$output = substr($output, 0, 100);
```

There are more elegant ways to handle cutting off at the end of the text than a strict 100-character limit, but the main bit I wanted to share was the `if` statement portion.